# Runtime exception while render template on play framework 2.1.1

Tags: java, akka, playframework-2.1

im using java play framework 2.1.1

i'm getting `InvocationTargetException` using `invoke` method.
 So to understand what exception was thrown in the invoked method i made this code:
https://github.com/jstar88/LibreTitan/blob/master/app/controllers/pages/player/Chat.java

```
//invoked function
public static Result show(User user) {
    try{
        return ok(chatIndex.render(user.skin));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
        ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
        return ok(errors.toString());
    }
}
```

and i got

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.
at play.mvc.Http$Context.current(Http.java:30)
at play.mvc.Http$Context$Implicit.flash(Http.java:167)
at views.html.game.chatIndex$.apply(chatIndex.template.scala:32)
at views.html.game.chatIndex$.render(chatIndex.template.scala:52)
at views.html.game.chatIndex.render(chatIndex.template.scala)
at controllers.pages.player.Chat.show(Chat.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at controllers.Rights.callController(Rights.java:73)
at controllers.Rights.access$000(Rights.java:14)
at controllers.Rights$1.call(Rights.java:32)
at controllers.Rights$1.call(Rights.java:30)
at akka.dispatch.Futures$$anonfun$future$1.apply(Future.scala:75)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:137)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1417)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

you can check all the code here https://github.com/jstar88/LibreTitan/tree/master/app,
maybe i made some logical error in templates? thank you

edit:same error happend also in 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

From your source code, you need the Flash scope in your template. Just add the implicit flash parameter in the beginning of your template:

```
@(skin: String)(implicit flash: Flash)
```

Comment: thank you. I tryed `@(skin: String)(implicit flash: play.api.mvc.Flash)` but now it say "error: method render in class chatIndex cannot be applied to given types;"

Comment: i also tryed play.mvc.Http.Flash but nothing change

Comment: Also change your controller, by calling `ok(chatIndex.render(user.skin, flash()));`